# Injective holomorphic/smooth map into a topological vector space vs immersion.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, topological-vector-spaces

In the finitely dimensional case it follows from the constant rank theorem that a smooth map between smooth manifolds, which is not an immersion on an open set, cannot be injective. I need a "semi-infinite" dimensional analogue of this fact.

Namely, let $U$ be a domain in $\mathbf{C}^{d}$, let $E$ be a topological vector space and let $\varphi:U\to E$ be holomorphic, such that the rank of $D\varphi_{x}$ is **less** than $d$ for every $x\in U$. Does it follow that $\varphi$ is **not** injective?

I understand that the constant rank theorem does exist for infinite dimensions, but it has a lot of technical conditions, which I suspect to be redundant if the domain is finitely dimensional. In particular, I am curious if we need $E$ to be good, e.g. isomorphic to a Banach space.

In fact, I can prove my claim; however I hope for a reference to a constant rank theorem or something else, that would just make my life simple =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant rank theorem is generally proved by gluing the submersion theorem and the immersion theorem : locally a constant rank map is obtained as $f= i\circ s$, where $i$ is an immersion and $c$ a submersion.

This work in your case. Let $r<d$ be the rank of $\phi$ on some open set $\Omega$ where it is constant and maximal.

For every continuous linear form on $E$ say $l\in E^*$, $\varphi ^*dl = d\varphi ^*l$ is an (exact) differential form on $M$, and at each point $x$ the subspace   $K _x$ of the dual of $\bf R^d$ (in fact of $T_x^*\Omega$) generated by these forms is of constant dimension $r$. We can therefore find a finite subset $l_1,..., l_{r}$ such that these forms are linearly independent in a neighborhood $\Omega '$ of a given point.

Now we can argue like in finite dimension.

The map $s$ defined by $s : \Omega ' \to \bf R^{r}$ defined by $s(x)= (l_1\circ \phi,...l_{r}\circ \phi )$ is a submersion (in particular is not injective).
In order to prove the "constant rank theorem" in this context, it is enough to check that $\varphi$ is constant along the fibers of $s$. To this end, note that
the kernel of the derivative $D\varphi $ at a point $x$,   $K_x$, is the the finite intersection of the kernels of the forms $\phi ^*dl _i$ at each point on $\Omega '$, this is the same as the  kernel of $Ds$

Comment: Ok, so the main idea is to find a collection of the elements of $E^*$, which "realize" the rank, and them just pretend we have a map into a finitely-dimensional space, right? If so, I kind of thought about the same, I hoped that it is already written somewhere, and I wouldn't have to write the proof in my paper...

Comment: More precisely, the constant rank theorem is obtained while combining the submersion theorem and the immersion theorem. The submersion theorem is enough for your purpose (it obnly uses finite dim of the source). I am not sure if the immersion theorem remains true in an infinite dim. context. What do you think ?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure who are the theorems that you are referring to. Nevertheless, I more or less understand your answer. Thank you for it!